# Specify the z-ordering of 2D patches in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, patch, z-order

I draw some 2D patches (triangles in this case) using the following code

```
patch('Faces',tris1,'Vertices',XX,'FaceColor','flat',...
            'FaceVertexCData',colors1,...
            'CDataMapping','scaled');
```

Then I draw a second group of 2D patches

```
patch('Faces',tris2,'Vertices',XX,'FaceColor','flat',...
            'FaceVertexCData',colors2,...
            'CDataMapping','scaled');
```

I would like this 2nd group to always be displayed on top of the first group (what is usually called "z-ordering", I believe).
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You could add Z values of 0 to your vertices for tris1 and Z values of 1 to your vertices for tris2 - i.e. making your plot "3d".